# Group Theory greatest common divisor and order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm work through Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra for my Groups and Symmetries class however I've been stuck trying to understand the following section for awhile.

The theorem is:
Let a be an element of order n in a group and let k be a positive
integer. Then:
$$<a^k> = <a^{gcd(n,k)}> \text{and }  |a^k| = \frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$$

Such that n = order of the element.

So the author proceeds to give an example such that:
For |a| = 30. We find,

$$ <a^{26}>, <a^{17}>, <a^{18}> $$

I have no idea where he gets these generators from. I understand the arithmetic using them to find other generators that give the same subgroup however no clue on where he gets them from.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8XON.jpg)

Comment: What is the example that he gives? What do we find about $\langle a^{26}\rangle$?

Comment: @Josh I've included the full example in my question. He doesn't really state how he got it.

Comment: Those are just three particular subgroups you are asked to understand. The author chose those three because they illustrate features of the theorem. That's where he "got them from". They have no other significance.

Comment: @EthanBolker That's what I kept thinking but I was confused because of the way he wrote them. Thank you for clarifying!